# Pass variable from one Javascript file to another when used in different HTML pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Sorry for the slightly confusing title, but couldn't find anything online to help me with the issue I am facing. Essentially, I have three Javascript files and two different HTML pages. In the first HTML page, let's say first.html, I have two buttons, let's call them Button 1 and Button 2. When the user clicks on Button 1, it opens up a Javascript function in javascript1.js which makes a call to a REST API. It then passes this data to javascript2.js by passing it as a parameter. Essentially, this is how it looks like:

javascript1.js

```
 function firstfunction() {
$.getJSON("http://website.com", function(data) {
     newfunction(data);
  }
}
```

Inside javascript2.js is

```
function newfunction(dataparameter) {
      alert(dataparameter); 
  }
```

This so far is working perfectly. However, some complications arise with the second button in first.html. Essentially, after the user clicks on the first button a second button becomes available which leads the user to a new html page, in this case second.html. Now inside this HTML page, I want to display the same data that javascript1.js produces in a file called javascript3.js. I have tried many options, such as using cookies, or passing it in a parameter, etc. However, I have been unable to do successfully do it as I am a bit confused on how to include the Javascript files in the HTML page. In first.html, I am including javascript1.js and javascript2.js. In the second.html, should I be including all three javascript files? I could just try to make the get call again in the new HTML page but I'd prefer to find a more efficient way. Please let me know if I should provide more code/explanation; hopefully this question makes sense! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is it strictly necessary for your project to have separate JS files for each page?  What happens when you need to add yet another HTML file?  Having a single JS file that you could reference within every HTML file you create seems more efficient.

Comment: how much data are we talking about? small amount of text, or medium/large amount of json/html?

Comment: @SimianAngel Sure, I can combine javascript1.js and javascript2.js successfully. However, I want data to be present in a third function that only alerts this data when the user clicks on Button 2 and goes to second.html. I'm confused on how I can do that since I'm including this javascript file in both HTML pages.

Comment: Right now I have defined a global variable in the top of the Javascript file and tried assigning the JSON value to it in the first function. However, when I call on the global variable in the third function, it is returning undefined.

Comment: @haxxxton its a small-medium amount of JSON, not too much

Comment: @trynacode have a look at localStorage, its simpler than cookies (imo) https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/ pay attention to the 'strings only' section

Comment: Ended up using local storage successfully. Hopefully, security-wise it is not too big of a deal.